# multiple files are merged into one dataframe - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have around 100 .csv stock files in a folder with some dummy data.
They are named like AA.csv, BB.csv, CC.csv.....
The file name "AA" "BB" "CC" are symbols here. Each dataframe will have a symbol. So here we have 100 symbols.

```
 Date           Open        High    Low          Close      Adj Close   Volume
2014-09-02  38.849998   38.990002   38.580002   38.740002   35.522366   6196200
2014-09-03  38.779999   38.965000   38.349998   38.395000   35.206020   6796800
2014-09-04  38.400002   38.685001   38.380001   38.580002   35.375645   5741000
```

I want to merge the 100 dataframes into a single dataframe. The final dataframe will have 101 columns.
A Date column and one column for each of the 100 symbols, this column will contain the return value we compute for that symbol. I want to merge such that it only contains the intersection of dates across symbols.

I know we can use concat by reading each csv file an combining them into one singal dataframe. But i want do this using "merge". Is it possible?
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) to merge the data based on the key "Date". As you might want to merge more than two dataframes at once, you can use [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html).

Say the data you read from CSV files would look like follows.

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date": ["2014-09-02", "2014-09-03", "2014-09-04"],
    "Open": [38.849998, 38.779999, 38.400002]
})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date": ["2014-09-02", "2014-09-03", "2014-09-04"],
    "High": [38.990002, 38.965000, 38.685001]
})

df_3 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date": ["2014-09-02", "2014-09-03", "2014-09-04"],
    "Low": [38.580002, 38.349998, 38.380001]
})

dfs = [df_1, df_2, df_3]
```

You then can do:

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

df = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['Date'],
                                     how='outer'), dfs)
```

df will then be:

```
         Date       Open       High        Low
0  2014-09-02  38.849998  38.990002  38.580002
1  2014-09-03  38.779999  38.965000  38.349998
2  2014-09-04  38.400002  38.685001  38.380001
```

You should also read the documentation about the 'how' parameter in the pandas documentation.